# PHP Limit output MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code :

```
$single_family  = "SELECT
field_1        as type ,            #0
field_246      as status,           #1 
field_232      as prop_sqft ,       #2
field_25       as numbeds,          #3 
field_10       as PostalCode ,      #4
field_214      as description,      #5
field_92       as Baths ,           #6
field_113      as Images ,          #7
field_102      as GarageSpaces ,    #8
field_25       as Beds ,            #9
field_1487     as Address ,         #10
field_137      as Price   ,         #11
field_sysid    as Image ,           #12
field_922      as city              #13

from properties limit 5 ";

    $single_family_run   = mysql_query($single_family);

    $single_family_show = mysql_fetch_array($single_family_run);

    while ($single_family_show) 

    {
           $type        = $single_family_show[0];
           echo $type;

    }
```

The problem I am having is that the limit statement is being ignored , and as a result the query is returning all the values instead of the 5 that I set on the limits. Can you help me to find the error?

Comment: Limit refers to the rows and not to the columns ...

Comment: those field names are scary, when they have numbers it usually means your db structure is borked

Comment: @dagon Thank you but your comment , but I believe it is really off-topic

Comment: You're not iterating through your results. You only have `while ($single_family_show)`.

Comment: ok i wont comment on how bad using mysql_* is either then ;(

Comment: @Dagon I know you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

(but you should not use `mysql...` it is deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO)

```
while ($single_family_show = mysql_fetch_array($single_family_run)) 

{
       $type        = $single_family_show[0];
       echo $type;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your database is a bit (very) messed up. Try learning about normalization [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Try using mysqli for your case:

```
$single_family  = "SELECT
field_1        as type ,            #0
field_246      as status,           #1 
field_232      as prop_sqft ,       #2
field_25       as numbeds,          #3 
field_10       as PostalCode ,      #4
field_214      as description,      #5
field_92       as Baths ,           #6
field_113      as Images ,          #7
field_102      as GarageSpaces ,    #8
field_25       as Beds ,            #9
field_1487     as Address ,         #10
field_137      as Price   ,         #11
field_sysid    as Image ,           #12
field_922      as city              #13

from properties limit 5 ";

$single_family_run   = mysqli_query($single_family);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($single_family_run))  {
       $type        = $row[0];
       echo $type;

}
```

Comment: I actually went into the easiest solution naming the fields like that in a database with hundreds of fields...but I agree with your statement

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you want the first 5 results, I believe you should use "LIMIT 0,5".

```
from properties LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: `LIMIT 5` is perfectly valid syntax